# Firebase authentication handling with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, redirect, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get Firebase authenticating to work with routers(ui-router) as in [this](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers) example. I want to have multiple pages where you can get without authenticating.

When a user is signed in and [signs out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) on a page where authentication is required, how do I manage to redirect the user to the 'home' state?

I thought of the following code in the run function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user == null) {
        $state.go('home');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this makes it impossible to get to the pages where you don't need authentication when you access them by URL.

You can find the full code example [here](http://jsbin.com/vonajupumu/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Version info would be helpful here. See also [Authenticating with routers in Angular 1.x](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers) and [Routing example in Angular 2.x for master/detail view with List Observable resolve](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/c493e19a932cd608b811907547be7a78).

Comment: I'm using Angular 1 and Firebase 3.6.4. As I said in my post I've used your first link, but when I signout is does not redirect me to the home state.

Comment: Without a repro it's going to be impossible to help with debugging. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is the example [code](http://jsbin.com/vonajupumu/edit?html,js,console,output). When you create a group, you are logged in and send to the share state. When you logout you should be send back to the home state.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you to have both conditions **undefined** and **null** as below

```
if(user == null || user == undefined ) {
        $state.go('home');
    }
```

Add these below in the resolve property for the pages that you don't want to be authenticated(allowing anonymous users to get in to)

```
resolve : {
       user: undefined;
}
```

**but if the user is allowed to be authenticated again he should LOGIN**

Add your user JSON object to help you out of this bug.